# Return address by geolocation

Tags: react-native

I have this code to return the address:

```
const geo = {

  getGeocode: (latitude, longitude) => {
    axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+ latitude +','+ longitude + __API_KEY__)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
        return response.data.results[0].formatted_address
     }).catch((error) => { 
       console.log( error.message )
     });
     return 'Error geocode'
  },

  getGeolocation: () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        console.log(position);
          return geo.getGeocode(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude); 
      },
      (error) => console.log( error.message ),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000 },
    );
    return 'Error geolocation';
  },

};

export default geo;
```

However every time I execute

```
import geolocation from './geolocation';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Address: {geolocation.getGeolocation()}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

this returns the `Error geolocation`

It returns on console the response with the address all right

I've tried it in many ways, and within what I know it should be returning the address correctly

**[EDIT]**

I tried this code too:

```
export const geo = {

  var: address = '...',

  getGeocode: (latitude, longitude) => {
    axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+ latitude +','+ longitude + __API_KEY__)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
        response.data.results[0].formatted_address;
     }).catch((error) => { 
       console.log( error.message )
     });
     return 'Error geocode';
  },

  getGeolocation: () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        console.log(position);
          geo.getGeocode(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude); 
      },
      (error) => console.log( error.message ),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000 },
    );
    return address;
  },

};
```

I return the `address` correctly, however I can not pass the value of `response.data.results[0].formatted_address` to variable `address`

How can I do this?